# how to "execute command on file in multiple subdirectories within containing folder" i.e cd into each subdirectory containing file and execute command

Tags: find, pushd

I have a file named filename.sh in different directories. I am trying to simultaneously submit this file to run on a number of cluster nodes. I need to find this file wherever they may be, cd into their containing folder and execute the command "sbatch run_code.sh" This is what I have tried.

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name filename.sh -exec sbatch run_code.sh {} \;
```

And it works except it runs command from current folder which does not contain dependencies needed to run the code.

alternatively I am leaning towards a for loop like this

```
for d in dirname; do 
  cd "$(dirname "$(find . -type f -name filename.sh)")" && sbatch run_code.sh)
done
```

which does not work. I look forward to getting some help here. Please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you want:

```
find . -name filename.sh -type f -execdir sbatch run_code.sh {} ';'
```

`-mindepth 1` is superflous. It excludes `.`, but `.` is excluded anyway by both `-type f` and `-name filename.sh`.

`-execdir` (from BSD), is not a standard `find` predicate, but chances are that if your `find` supports `-mindepth` (also non-standard though from GNU), it will also support `-execdir`.

`-execdir` is exactly for that. It's like `-exec` except it runs the command in the parent directory of the selected file. Here, depending on the `find` implementation, the command being run will be either `sbatch run_code.sh ./filename.sh` or `sbatch run_code.sh filename.sh`. Remove the `{}` if you don't want the `filename.sh` to be passed as an argument to the command.

With `find` implementations that don't support `-execdir`, you could do:

```
find . -name filename.sh -type f -exec sh -c '
  cd "${1%/*}" && exec sbatch run_code.sh "${1##*/}"' sh {} ';'
```

`${1%/*}` is `$1` but with the shortest tail matching `/*` removed, so it will act like `"$(dirname -- "$1")"` but is more efficient and more reliable¹. `${1##*/}` removes the longest head matching `*/` giving you a `basename`-like result.

Or to avoid running one `sh` per file:

```
find . -name filename.sh -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    (cd "${file%/*}" && exec sbatch run_code.sh "${file##*/}"
  done' sh {} +
```

With the `zsh` shell, you could also do:

```
for f (./**/filename.sh(ND.)) (cd $f:h && sbatch run_code.sh $f:t)
```

(the `exec` (to save a process) is not necessary as `zsh` does it implicitly already for the last command run in the subshell).

`$f:h` expands to `$f`'s `h`ead (dirname) and `$f:t` to its `t`ail (basename).

---

<sup>¹ would still work for instance if the dir name ended in newline characters; there are cases where using `dirname` (or `zsh`'s `$var:h`) gives better results though such when the path to get the `dirname` of doesn't have any `/` or ends in `/` characters.</sup>

Comment: Thank you. The first option worked and I understand your explanations. I will be looking at how the other options works.